# Understanding Objective-C BOOL Type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

If I have the following function:

```
-(BOOL) checkIfValid{
   if(someThing){
      return YES;
   }
   return NO;
}
```

Can I then do this in another function:

```
if([self checkIfValid]){
   //do something
}
```

I am slightly confused by the BOOL type and the YES/NO values....is YES synonymous to TRUE and same for NO and false?

Comment: You are right, YES is the Objective-C equivalent of TRUE and NO is the equivalent to FALSE

Comment: you can use that because method is returning BOOL value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt refer documentation

```
#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use

```
if([self checkIfValid]) 
{
   //do something if checkIfValid returns YES/True
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes ucabdro,

Your code is absolutely right and here YES stands for TRUE and NO stands for FALSE.